# after ajax call , the code after waiting for Json response could not be executed

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I have used Django2 to develop a web app.
I frontend, after the ajax call, the network tab on chrome dev does show the 200 status code, but I did not see any alert box. my app stuck at this line for waiting json: const msg_json = await response.json();  , the following alert does not execute

```js
async function myFunction() {
  Swal.fire({
    title: '',
    text: "Do you want to confirm entries?",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
    cancelButtonText: 'No'
  }).then(
    async(result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/content_checklist_name_url/',
          type: 'POST',
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            var comment_html = "<div id='myform_1'>" + data['log_info'] + "</div>";
            $('#myform_1').remove();
            $('#ajax_data').prepend(comment_html);
            $('#myform_input').val('');
          },

        });
        const response = await fetch({ % url 'bms:content_checklist_name_url' %
        });
        const msg_json = await response.json();

        alert(msg_json.responseText)
        let a = msg_json;
        if (a === "Duplicate Entry. This Course Code already exists.") {
          Swal.fire({
            title: '',
            text: 'Duplicate Entry. This Course Code already exists.',
            type: 'error',
          })


        } else {
          Swal.fire({
            title: '',
            text: 'Entries have been saved.',
            type: 'success',
          })


        }
        // },
        // failure: function(data)
        // {
        //  alert('Got an error dude');
        //  }
        // });
      } else {
        window.stop();
      }
    }
  )
}
```

```html
<form id="myform" action="/content_checklist_name_url/" method="POST">
  ...
</form>
<button class="button" onclick="myFunction()" type="button" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

backend view.py:

```
    @csrf_exempt
def content_checklist_name_url(request):

  if request.method == 'POST':    
    
         ...
    msg = "success"   

    obj = {"msg": msg}

    context = {'msg_json': json.dumps(obj)}
    return render(request, 'bms/main.html',context=context)
```

I got the error in the console: `VM355:4 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 3`

no alert box shows.

How could I check where goes wrong?

Comment: Where and how does `myFunction()` get called? The ajax should be in the form submit handler. You call `.submit()` and then call the ajax. That sequence doesn't make sense

Comment: You should dump jQuery's `$.ajax` and use the native `fetch` instead. `const response = await fetch(url); const msg_json = await response.json();` Job done

Comment: @JeremyThille   updated my question, using ur method generated new problem

Comment: Uh? You didn't use my method. You're still using both `$.ajax` and `await fetch` together.

Answer (score 2):

Your view is waiting for a POST and you are sending a GET so this branch won’t be executed. Also, submitting a form by html, make the browser change pages so as the form is submitted, the ajax won’t be called.

Comment: how to fix then?

Comment: Use ajaxForm and send it with POST

Comment: used ur method, I could not receive the response, I have updated the code, please see my updated question

Comment: I think the problem is $(this).serialise as this is not the form, check what is the browser sending to Django through the network tab in console.